# How to turn off selenium messages python?

Tags: python, selenium

When I add_option('headless') to my browser. I get these messages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTZmn.png

and I really want to turn off it(in console will be messages, which I print()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Selenium Webdriver you have the option log-level

To just have error message use this argument as :

```py
driver.add_argument('log-level=3')
```